# ASP.Net MVC Razor Dropdownlist with submit button postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

First off, I am new to ASP.NET MVC and having a hard time finding good resources (API?) for it. So my question comes two-fold:

I want to try and get my dropdownlist to not auto-postback. Instead, I'm trying to get the dropdownlist to simply select an item, and then allow a submit button to submit the GET request.

So if the code example I am looking at looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm" })){
     @Html.DropDownList(
         "CategoryID", 
         (SelectList) ViewData["Categories"], 
         "--Select One--", 
         new{ onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();" }
     ) 
 }
```

how do I alter this to instead put a a submit button to do a GET request?

Secondly, anyone have any good literature that would resemble some sort of API for razor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add an `input type='submit'` element to the form.  (And of course, change to `FormMethod.Get`.)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "TheForm" })) 
{
    @Html.DropDownList( "CategoryID", 
        (SelectList) ViewData["Categories"], 
        "--Select One--", 
        new{ onchange = "document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();" }
    ) 

    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
}
```

As far as API documentation, I think the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416515%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is as close as you will get.